# How to set background image for one specific page on Theme based Wordpress page?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, background-image

I'm using BeTheme for my wordpress site. Now I want to change one of may page's body background by setting a background image(only for that page).

I tried changing my style.css by adding this as I learnt this would do the job for me.

```
body.page-id-269 { 
background-image: url("http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/your-background-image.jpg")!important; 
background-position: center center!important;  
background-repeat: repeat!important; 
}
```

How can I set the bg imge for that perticular page body?(I'm using BeTheme theme)

**UPDATE**

As Below answer mentioned I tried these changes, in my functions.php I added

```
add_filter('body_class', 'change_body_classes');

function change_body_classes($classes) {
    if( is_page( 'page-id-269' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'my-background-class';
        return $classes;
    }
}
```

And in my style .css I added this,

```
 .my-background-class{ 
    background-image: url("http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/your-background-image.jpg")!important; 
    background-position: center center!important;  
    background-repeat: repeat!important; 
    }
```

Comment: You could create a JS variable within said page, then write an `if` statement looking for the variable and changing the `background-image` property if it returns true

Comment: What happened when you changed your style.css? Does the body have the appropriate class? Did you make sure that you browser cache wasn't giving you old CSS?

Comment: @janh: nothing happened.  yes I removed the cache and my added css part was in my style.css.

Comment: What about the body-tag, what classes are added to it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `body_class` filter to add a class to that specific page with your css.

```
add_filter('body_class', 'change_body_classes');

function change_body_classes($classes) {
    if( is_page( 'my-page' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'my-background-class';
        return $classes;
    }
}
```

Comment: then again, how can i add thee css part?

Comment: Create a class within your style.css with the CSS you have written.

Comment: instead of 'my-page' in your code i put my page-id. and created the css part, still doesn't work and it changes all my apge styles. thanks.

Comment: First i added your code to my functions.php. Instead of 'my-page' i put my page id there, 'page-id-220'. Then in my css I created a class call my-background-class and added my bg attributes. that's it..

Comment: You need to post all your code in the question so I can see what you have done for myself.  Unless 'page-id-220' is the slug of the page then that is the wrong way to do it because the page id is a number not a string.

Comment: When you inspect element in the browser, is it applying the style? Does the browser at least think it does? Any console errors? Maybe a 404 on image?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are not using the correct format for the page id, the page id is just a number not a slug like you have in your code example.  Instead of is_page( 'page-id-269' ) it should just be is_page( 269 ) unless your page slug is 'page-id-269'.